# How do we interpret frequency from fft command in matlab?

Tags: signal, signal-processing, matlab

How do we interpret frequency from fft command in matlab? When I apply fft to a sampled function(@ Fs) and I get peaks at some values in the fft array. How do I know what frequency in Hertz does it correspond to?

Comment: watch out for the fact that MATLAB arrays are 1-based, not 0-based, so the DC (zero frequency) term is in array[1], not array[0]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The output of the fft function will go from 0 Hz to fs/2, then -fs/2 to almost 0.  If you ignore the 2nd half (for purely real signals), the following works well:

For n samples at a sampling rate of fs, you can create a frequency axis, f with the following formula:

f = (0:n-1)/n*fs

This gives you freqs from fs/2 to almost fs, but if you overlook that...

The other option is to use the fftshift command on the fft output and revise the formula

f = (0:n-1)/n*fs-fs/2